# How to copy geckodriver to path /usr/local/bin/ in Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: linux, selenium, gitlab-ci, pipeline, geckodriver

I'm using this command to copy geckodriver to the path but I still encounter a problem

```
- wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.0/geckodriver-v0.29.0-linux64.tar.gz
- echo "geckodriver downloaded successfully"
- tar -xvzf geckodriver*
- chmod +x geckodriver
- export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

ERROR : 

==============================================================================
Firefox                                                                       
==============================================================================

WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Install [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) package and add to your requirements.txt file:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and use like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

with that package, you should worry about geckodriver anymore

Comment: you mean that the scripts need to add in the requirements.txt?

Comment: @RueL no, script what I have written adding instead of your driver initialization and make pip freeze > requirements.txt, that gitlab install all of the new dependencies there with new webdriver_manager.
does your code works locally?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I was able now to fix my issue. Thank you for helping me. :) thumbs up!!!!

Comment: @RueL please, confirm the asnwer like solved, I will get rewards and reputation, cheers!